# Is this the correct way to implement dictionary?

Tags: python, file, if-statement, dictionary, output

```
       f=open('food.dat','w+')
       rates=0
       rate=0
       print"Menu is:"
       print"""   1.Starters
       2.Main Courses
       3.Snacks
       4.Drinks
       5.Desserts"""
       hotel_food1={1:'Starters',
       2:'Main Courses',
       3:'Snacks',
       4:'Drinks',
       5:'Desserts'}
       while True:
           food=input("Enter the food type:")
           if(hotel_food1.has_key(food)==1):
                     print"Menu is:"
                     print"""1.Salmon Devilled Eggs
                     2.Baked Parika Cheese
                     3.Ricotta and Parmesan Fritters
                     4.Traditional Welsh Cawl
                     5.Summer Ratatouille Salad"""
                     hotel_starter={1:'Salmon Devilled Eggs',
                      2:'Baked Parika Cheese',
                      3:'Ricotta and Parmesan Fritters',
                      4:'Traditional Welsh Cawl',
                      5:'Summer Ratatouille Salad'}
                     fd=input("ENter the food type")
                     if(hotel_starter.has_key(fd)==1):
                                               rate=rate+234
                     elif(hotel_starter.has_key(fd)==2):
                                          rate=rate+345
                     elif(hotel_starter.has_key(fd)==3):
                                       rate=rate+200
                     elif(hotel_starter.has_key(fd)==4):
                                       rate=rate+110
                     elif(hotel_starter.has_key(fd)==5):
                                        rate=rate+334
                     ch=raw_input("Do you want to continue? yes/no??")
                     if(ch=='no'):
                              break
       rates=rates+rate

       f.write(str(rates))


       f.seek(0,0)
       x=f.read()
       print x

       f.close()
```

Hello, In the above program when i give input for food as 1 and fd as 1 ,i must get the value 234 printed.but when i run the program i get value as 0. Is there something wrong with the indentation? Is the dictionary implemented correctly?? please help!Thank you!

Comment: Using which version of python? Are you sure the input passed an `int` to `fd`?

Comment: i am using python 2.7 version.

Comment: I get a printed value of 234: http://i.imgur.com/7uMSdCh.png

Comment: can you tell me the indentation, because its not working in mine.

Comment: I have copied your code *exactly* as you have presented it, and run it through console/command prompt.  There is no indentation error.

Comment: now if you try food=1 and fd=2 you will still get 234 not 345

Comment: `has_key` returns boolean, which is `==1`, so as long as user inputs a key which exist in the dictionary, the first test will always evaluate true, since `has_key(fd)` == True and `True == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

`has_key` returns boolean, which is `==1`, so as long as user inputs a key which exist in the dictionary, the first test will always evaluate true, since `has_key(fd)` == True and `True == 1`.  So you need to revise your logic.

I think you are going about this the wrong way, though, as it is quickly devolving in to spaghetti code of if/elif/else statements when you can more appropriately deal with this by nesting dictionaries.  This will also help with readability.

You may look at initializing and nesting your dictionaries properly, and include the rate as part of the dict.  This is just an example:

```
hotel_starters = {1:{'item':'Salmon Devilled Eggs', 'rate':234},
                 2:{'item':'Baked Parika Cheese', 'rate':345},
                 3:{'item':'Ricotta and Parmesan Fritters', 'rate':'456'}
                 }
hotel_main_courses = {1:{'item':'Filet Mignon', 'rate':678},
                 2:{'item':'Vegetarian Lasagna', 'rate':567},
                 3:{'item':'Halibut', 'rate':'890'}
                 }
hotel_menu = {1:hotel_starters,
             2: hotel_main_courses}
```

Using that sort of data structure, you can easily query by key:

```
hotel_menu[1] # returns the entire 'hotel_starters' dictionary

hotel_menu[1][1]  # returns the dictionary for hotel_starters[1]

hotel_menu[1][1]['rate'] # returns the rate associated with that item, etc.
```

And further, to print your menu:

```
for k, v in hotel_menu['starters'].items():
    print k, v['item'], v['rate']
```

So in an example you can do:

```
# initialize your menu dictionaries
hotel_starters = {1:{'item':'Salmon Devilled Eggs', 'rate':234},
                 2:{'item':'Baked Parika Cheese', 'rate':345},
                 3:{'item':'Ricotta and Parmesan Fritters', 'rate':'456'}
                 }
hotel_main_courses = {1:{'item':'Filet Mignon', 'rate':678},
                 2:{'item':'Vegetarian Lasagna', 'rate':567},
                 3:{'item':'Halibut', 'rate':'890'}
                 }
hotel_menu = {1:hotel_starters,
             2: hotel_main_courses}  


rates=0
menu = input('1 for starters, 2 for main courses:')
if menu in hotel_menu:
    print 'menu is:\n'
    for k, v in hotel_menu[menu].items():
        print k, v['item'], v['rate'] 
    food = input('enter your food item:\n')
    if food in hotel_menu[menu]:
        rates += hotel_menu[menu][food]['rate']
```